# add categories present in dictionary that are not present in the data to counts output - python

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating some counts of the categories per columns in a df. All possible categories are not present in the column - but they are stored in a dictionary. Is there a possible way to append the categories not in the data back into the value_counts data? see below for some code and examples of the expected output. there are many of these columns so its not good to append at the end manually. Thank you so much!

dictionary with all possible responses

```
df_dic = {'veggie': ['cucumber', 'broccoli', 'spinach', 'kale', 'potatoe', 'pepper', 'tomatoe'],
          'fruit': ['banana', 'orange', 'grapes', 'pear', 'melon', 'apple']}
```

data

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('cucumnber', 'apple'),
                   ('broccoli', 'pear'),
                   ('spinach', 'orange'),
                   ('spinach', 'orange'),
                   ('kale', 'apple'),
                   ('kale', 'banana'),
                   ('potatoe', 'pear')],
                  columns=['veggie', 'fruit'])
```

value_counts command

```
dat = []

for col in df:
    out_num = pd.DataFrame(df[col].value_counts()).sort_index().add_suffix('_num')
    out_per = pd.DataFrame(df[col].value_counts(normalize=True)*100).sort_index().add_suffix('_per')
    out = pd.concat([out_num, out_per], axis=1)
    dat.append(out)
```

output e.g. for dat[0]

```
          veggie_num  veggie_per
broccoli            1   14.285714
cucumnber           1   14.285714
kale                2   28.571429
potatoe             1   14.285714
spinach             2   28.571429
```

expected output

```
         veggie_num  veggie_per
brocoli            1   14.285714
cucumber           1   14.285714
kale                2   28.571429
potatoe             1   14.285714
spinach             2   28.571429
pepper              0   00.00
tomatoe             0   00.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) from the values in `df_dic` before adding to `dat`:

```
dat = []

for col in df:
    out_num = pd.DataFrame(df[col].value_counts()).sort_index().add_suffix('_num')
    out_per = pd.DataFrame(df[col].value_counts(normalize=True)*100).sort_index().add_suffix('_per')
    out = pd.concat([out_num, out_per], axis=1).reindex(df_dic[col], fill_value=0)
    dat.append(out)
```

`dat[0]`:

```
          veggie_num  veggie_per
cucumber           1   14.285714
broccoli           1   14.285714
spinach            2   28.571429
kale               2   28.571429
potato             1   14.285714
pepper             0    0.000000
tomato             0    0.000000
```

*Note values will need to match in spelling for this to work correctly.

---

With some simplifications:

```
dat = []

for col in df:
    out = df[col].value_counts().to_frame().add_suffix('_num')
    out[f'{col}_per'] = (df[col].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100)
    out = out.reindex(df_dic[col], fill_value=0)
    dat.append(out)
```

`dat[0]`:

```
          veggie_num  veggie_per
cucumber           1   14.285714
broccoli           1   14.285714
spinach            2   28.571429
kale               2   28.571429
potato             1   14.285714
pepper             0    0.000000
tomato             0    0.000000
```

---

DataFrame and `dict` used:

```
df_dic = {
    'veggie': ['cucumber', 'broccoli', 'spinach', 'kale', 'potato', 'pepper',
               'tomato'],
    'fruit': ['banana', 'orange', 'grapes', 'pear', 'melon', 'apple']
}

df = pd.DataFrame([('cucumber', 'apple'),
                   ('broccoli', 'pear'),
                   ('spinach', 'orange'),
                   ('spinach', 'orange'),
                   ('kale', 'apple'),
                   ('kale', 'banana'),
                   ('potato', 'pear')],
                  columns=['veggie', 'fruit'])
```